# Why does html5 boilerplate use Twipsy and Prototype when it builds jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5boilerplate

So I just finished writing a single page with [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and everything is find with the dev code (the original one I just finished writing). Google Chrome and Firefox love it and display it well.

So I use the ant script ( ant build or ant text to skip jpeg/png optimization ) and browse to /publish/ to view it. And I got a javascript error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Twipsy' of undefined
```

But the fact is I never used Twipsy or prototype, just jQuery ... so I run a javascript debug console and see in the generated javascript file a reference to Twipsy and Prototype. But I never use any of those in my code. So what's wrong ? and what can I do ?

Comment: seems the htm5boilerplate had a very strong cache and we must delete all /publish and /intermediate manually before rebuild project. Otherwise the builder continues to use files that no longer exists and it causes errors.

Comment: if the above comment is the solution to the problem, then write it as an answer and mark it as "Accepted" using the tick icon. This will help others looking for answers to similar problems.

Comment: @Spudley : when i comment this question, i'm just making test, so i find it appropriate to not too quick mark it as answered. btw thx for the reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html5Boilerplate use a kind of very strong cache which actually keep the files you already delete in your project and always inline / include it in future build. You must delete `publish` and `intermediate` forlder to kepp your builder up to date.